# resultout used in oracle workflow

Tags: oracle, workflow

what is resultout used in oracle workflow,function activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is standard OUT parameter which you use to inform WF Engine about completion status of activity.

Information from [Workflow Guide](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/A60725_05/pdf/wfug.pdf):

> If a result type is specified in the Activities
>   properties page for the activity in the Oracle
>   Workflow Builder, this parameter represents the
>   expected result that is returned when the
>   procedure completes. The possible results are:
>
> COMPLETE:*<result_code>* -- activity completes
>   with the indicated result code. The result code
>   must match one of the result codes specified in the
>   result type of the function activity.
>
> WAITING -- activity is pending, waiting on
>   another activity to complete before it completes.
>   An example is the Standard ’AND’ activity.
>
> DEFERRED:*<date>* -- activity is deferred to a
>   background engine for execution until a given date.
>    must be of the format:
>   to_char(<date_string>, wf_engine.date_format)
>
> NOTIFIED:*<notification_id>*:*<assigned_user>* -- an external entity is notified that an action must be
>   performed. A notification ID and an assigned user
>   can optionally be returned with this result. Note
>   that the external entity must call CompleteActivity( )
>   to inform the Workflow Engine when the action
>   completes.
>
> ERROR:*<error_code>* -- activity encounters an
>   error and returns the indicated error code.